# How to write custom parser for arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am in a situation where I come across a string like "(d, a, b=2, c=3)" and I need to parse it into *args and **kwargs.

I tried using the ast module but it cannot convert the Assign operators to key, value pairs. `eval` gives similar error too and also I would like to avoid eval.

Note, I would like to avoid split on `,` because the input could be of the form:

`"(d, [b,c], e=3, f=[5,6])"`

Here is what I am trying:

```
>>import ast
>>input_args = "(d, a, b=2, c=3)" 
>>ast_tree = ast.parse(input_args)
```

I get:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse
     return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
 File "<unknown>", line 1
     (d, a, b=2, c=3)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can someone provide and clues on how to do this or which module to could help in doing this in a neat way?

Comment: [May help](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/)

Answer (score 1):

Simply put a dummy function name on the front:

```
input_args = "dummy(d, a, b=2, c=3)"
ast_tree = ast.parse(input_args)
```